# Transform an array of documents using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am running a special query in which I want transform the results after.

```
User.find({}, function(err, users) {
  // I want to remove/add some properties from/to each user here
});
```

Is there a way to transform an array of documents?  Also this is a special case so I do not want to apply a transformation to the Schema, which I think would transform each document like I want, but would also affect all other queries to the User model.

Basically I want the ability to perform a one time transformation on the array of docs returned.

```
User.find({}, function(err, users) {
  // I want to remove/add some properties to each user here
  users.toJSON({transform: function(doc,ret,options) { /* do tranform*/ });
  // That will not work as I get an error that toJSON is not defined for that
  // array that was returned.
});
```

I might be able to fake it out by adding a transformation right before I query and then removing that transformation when the query is complete, but that is a pretty bad hack IMHO.

Ideas?  Did I miss something in the docs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [`lean`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) query so that an array of plain JS objects are returned from the query and then use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the array:

```
User.find({}).lean().exec(err, users) {
    users = users.map(function(user) {
        // transform user into newuser as needed.
        ...
        return newuser;
    });
});
```

Comment: Works great, thanks.  Hoping there was a way to transform each object before I get the array back.  In the end its the same loop regardless just on my end instead of mongoose.

Comment: Note: `lean` has consequences other than turning a query into plain JS objects, such as getting rid of virtuals, methods, etc. What I needed was just to use the `toObject()` method on the items in the query (using `map`) instead.

Comment: @Nate can you please help me in understanding how to use toObject() on an array of documents.

Comment: @rakeshkashyap: `var usersObj = users.map(function (user) { return user.toObject(); });`

Comment: @rakeshkashyap Or, these days: `let usersObj = users.map(user => user.toObject());`