# Transform results of an array returned by Mongoose find function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have added a transform function to my Schema's `toObject` to strip certain properties, and change the name of `_id` to `id`. It works great when I use `findOne` and call `toObject` on the result, but I also have a `find({}, (err, items) => {...})` command. There's no way to call `toObject` on the array.

Here's my schema:

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    version: {type: String, default: '1.0.0'},
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    modified: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    properties: Schema.Types.Mixed
  }, {
  toObject: {
    transform: (doc, ret) => {
      // remove the _id and __v of every document before returning the result
      ret.id = doc.id;
      delete ret._id;
      delete ret.__v;
    }
  }
});
```

I've looked it up, and could only find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795219/transform-an-array-of-documents-using-mongoose?s=2%7C1.2601), where the recommended answer is to use `lean()` - which does not help me.

As a workaround, I added the line `var result = items.map(x => x.toObject());`, and while it works great, I wonder if there's a way to trigger the transform automatically on any document returned - single or array, so I won't have to iterate over the results.

Comment: as I understand it, you shouldnt have to call `toObject` manually if you have added the correct [options](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toObject) to the schema. could you provide code for how you added the transformation to `toObject`? I suspect the key is there

Comment: @rompetroll added schema code. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after looking around for a while, I finally settled on converting the results to objects myself. As mentioned in the question, instead of: `return items;` I have `return items.map(x => x.toObject());`

Answer (score 1):

I’ve created a mongoose plugin to do things like that.

```
 var cleanup = function (schema) {
     var toJSON = schema.methods.toJSON || mongoose.Document.prototype.toJSON;

     schema.set('toJSON', {
         virtuals: true
     });

     schema.methods.toJSON = function () {
         var json = toJSON.apply(this, arguments);

         delete json._id;
         delete json.__t;
         delete json.__v;

         return json;
     };
 };
```

Basically, it overrides `toJSON` (though you can do the same with `toObject`).

By the way, there’s already an `id` virtual property, defined by mongoose (unless you set `id` to `false` in the schema options).

I use it as such:

```
ItemSchema.plugin(cleanup);
```

Comment: Thanks @Bertrand, I understand I can do this with plugins, but I was wondering if I can just use the transform function - I thought that was its purpose.